# What is the meaning of [\w\-] regular expression in PHP

Tags: regex, preg-match

I was trying to understand about validating email in the following link -
http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_form_url_email.asp

I know that \w means alphanumeric characters i.e. [0-9a-zA-Z] and - should mean to include a "-" as well. I got confused because they have used it after the "." as well, I think that after "." only alphanumeric characters can appear such as "com" , "org" etc.

Comment: Yes, well, W3Schools is a terrible resource, and that regular expression is wrong. It won’t even match the common `a+b@example.com`. [This is how a valid e-mail address is defined.](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322#section-3.4)

Comment: @minitech I agree that the regex in OP's link is bad but your link isn't exactly helpful either..

Comment: This would be the library i'd pull to [validate an email address](http://www.regxlib.com/Search.aspx?k=email)

Comment: I would just like to say, with the recent RFC 6531 (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6531#page-7), Unicode characters are allowed. I think the best thing to do is to send an email and wait for a reply. Otherwise, you don't know if the email is valid.

Comment: @CrayonViolent: It’s not really intended to be. This, on the other hand: https://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### [Regex 101](http://regex101.com/r/cT1rB2)

**\w explained**

```
\w match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
```

**\w\- explained**

```
\w\-
    \w match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
    \- matches the character - literally
```

---

### [Matching Email Addresses](http://regex101.com/r/qN5eS8) Simple, not future proof

```
\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}\b
```

Comment: fyi this email regex won't jive with a lot of the new TLDs that have already and are going to be coming out. e.g. `me@mysite.solutions`

Comment: @CrayonViolent completely agree, I didn't want to show the complex regex.  I much prefer to show the simple answer, and allow the OP to know that there are more complex answers out there.

Answer (score 4):

`\w` means `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

and

`\-` means `-` (literal) in a character class.

Thus `[\w\-]` means `[a-zA-Z0-9-]`

note that escaping `-` in a character class is useless if it is at the first or last position.

Comment: I did not downvote it, but perhaps the reason for that down vote is that \w, in any flavor that supports unicode, (and I believe PHP does that), will also match many characters from other scripts.  So if you only want to match [a-zA-Z0-9_], and nothing else, that's probably how you should write it.

Comment: Someone might have downvoted you because you didn’t answer the question in the second paragraph, though… the OP seems to understand what you’ve answered with.